# When trying to redirect using HTACESS, a string "/redirect:/" gets embedded with the url

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, directory, url-rewriting

I have setup two domains to point to the same hosting server. For eg: the domains be :

1. example1.com
2. example2.com

I have created a directory called 'home' in my root, and whenever the 2nd domain is accessed, it should get redirected to the home directory. 
For eg: example2.com/post.php should get redirected to example2.com/home/post.php
I have done this by creating an htaccess file in my root directory with the following contents:

---

```
Options +FollowSymLinks 
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} example2.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !home
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ./home/$1
```

---

This is working perfectly. Now, i have a second requirement where i need to redirect users to a php file  (post.php) inside home directory whenever the user accesses the url example2.com/gallery/somestring.

So, i created a second htaccess file in my home directory and entered the following code:

---

```
Options +FollowSymLinks

RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^gallery/([^/]+)$ post.php?post=$1
```

---

But, whenever i try to access the url example2.com/gallery/somestring, it shows a strange 404 Not Found error :

---

```
The requested URL /home/redirect:/home/gallery.html/somestring/somestring was not found on this server.

Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.
```

---

Here. "redirect:" string is getting concatenated to the redirected URL somehow.

Can any one please give me some idea as to why its happening ??

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem. I am sharing this if any one gets into this same problem and finds this post. The problem was that there was a file gallery.html in my root folder. This was causing this error. Just delete this file or rename the file to some thing else. Thats it :)